# How get only year with type XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, spring, xmlgregoriancalendar

i have a XML Jaxb class to set with XMLGregorianCalendar type. But we are supposed to set only year in this attribute.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new 
GregorianCalendar());
xmlCal.setYear(2021);
xmlObject.setBuiltYear(xmlCal); 
// xmlCal.getYear() will give me year but its type int , so setter method not accepting it. If 
has to be of type XMLGregorianCalendar  only with year.
```

If i set it like above its giving `2021-09-23T10:19:38.346-04:00` but i need only year with type XMLGregorianCalendar  . how we can do that ?

Comment: Just setting the year asyou do should be enough. The XSD type should be a year, so converting it to XML should leave out the other fields.

Comment: But in XSD its XMLGregorianCalendar which i cannot change

Comment: No it isn't. XSD isn't Java, it is the desciptor on which this java code was generated and also used for mapping it back. I strongly suggest to readup on what an XSD is. All date/time types in XML (without type converters) will endup as an `XMLGregorianCalendar`. Just set it as you do now, JAXB should in the end only output the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`XMLGregorianCalendar#clear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#clear()) before setting the year.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new GregorianCalendar());
        xmlCal.clear();
        xmlCal.setYear(2021);
        System.out.println(xmlCal);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/zuFMNh)

Comment: Thanks That works

Comment: I suggest you use the no-arg factory method: `XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();`. This gives you an `XMLGregorianCalendar` with all fields undefined or `null` so you won’t need `clear()`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash is good and correct. There are other ways to obtain the same, so as a supplement I am presenting a couple.

Edit: A simpler and shorter variant of the code by Arvind Kumar Avinash:

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal
            = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
    xmlCal.setYear(2021);
    System.out.println(xmlCal);
```

Output:

> 2021

The no-arg `newXMLGregorianCalendar()` gives us an `XMLGregorianCalendar` with all fields undefined or `null`. Set the year, and we’re done.

You may also create your desired `XMLGregorianCalendar` fully complete directly from a factory method call. Here’s a longish variant:

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(2021, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED,
                    DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
```

The result is the same as before. The fields that I set undefined are month, day of month and UTC offset (called *timezone* with `XMLGregorianCalendar`).

A much shorter variant is:

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal
            = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2021");
```

Output is still the desired:

> 2021

Just as you want an `XMLGregorianCalendar` for the purpose of producing a specific string, the `XMLGregorianCalendar` can also be constructed from the string you want.

In case you had your year in an `int`, you may convert first:

```
    int year = 2021;
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(String.valueOf(year));
```

It may feel like a waste to convert your `int` to a `String` only to have it parsed again. You decide.

Which way to prefer? It’s a matter of taste.

### java.time.Year

As an aside, only if your class requires an `XMLGregorianCalendar`, use that class. For all other purposes I recommend the `Year` class:

```
    Year year = Year.of(2021);
    System.out.println(year);
```

> 2021